# What Event fires after a Flex chart has refreshed

Tags: apache-flex

When executing dataprovider.refresh() for a chart component it redraws the chart.

How do I determin when the chart is redrawn?

I would like to take a png screen shot of the chart when it is fully drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wait until chart finishes its rendering. After the code, which performs redrawing logic is executed, `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` is dispatched. And you can see redrawn chart on the next screen update. Try the following code:

```
private function someFunc():void
{
    //YOU'RE HERE BEFORE CALLING REFRESH
    dataprovider.refresh();
    chart.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onUpdate);
}

private function onUpdate(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    chart.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onUpdate);
    callLater(takeScreenshot);
}

private function takeScreenshot():void
{
    //TAKE SCREENSHOT LOGIC HERE
}
```